# Is there any way to resolve datetime datatype error while using insert into (columns) select (columns) from table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I am trying to backup a table in database and tried Insert into select statement for copying whole data into the new table. For Identity column I have mentioned the column names and make the set_identity ON and query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO backup_ApplicationProjectMapping (ModifiedOn, ModifiedBy, CreatedOn, CreatedBy, IsDeleted, ProjectId, ApplicationId, MappingId)
    SELECT
        ModifiedOn, ModifiedBy, CreatedOn, CreatedBy,
        IsDeleted, ProjectId, ApplicationId, MappingId  
    FROM
        GenericDME_Training.[dbo].ApplicationProjectMapping
    EXCEPT 
    (SELECT TOP 0 * 
     FROM GenericDME_Training.[dbo].ApplicationProjectMapping)
```

While executing it, it is showing datetime can not be implicitly convert into int datatype, use convert function to run this query. I do not understand why this datatype error happens, as I am not trying to convert datetime to anything? Please help!

Source Table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9z3g.png)

BackUp table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zhYG.png)

Comment: Show us your table structures (columns and their datatypes) of all tables involved....

Comment: First I have used Select * into bckup_table from sourcetable. which worked fine and table rows and datatypes are same. next while inserting into that same table from source table it is showing error.

Answer (score 3):

Remove that

```
EXCEPT 
(SELECT TOP 0 * 
 FROM GenericDME_Training.[dbo].ApplicationProjectMapping)
```

Your picture is

[image]

but you've swapped the column order around in the first query:

```
SELECT ModifiedOn...
```

compared to what the the `SELECT *` will retrieve (the columns in order of your picture) in the second query:

```
SELECT MappingId...
```

"except top 0 rows" is a non op/nonsense anyway but if you plan to later `EXCEPT SELECT TOP N` where N is non zero, then you have to match the order (well, strictly speaking just just make sure that the columns are type compatible) of the columns on each side of the EXCEPT. You cannot do things like this:

```
SELECT DateColumn, IntColumn
UNION
SELECT IntColumn, DateColumn

SELECT DateColumn, IntColumn
EXCEPT
SELECT IntColumn, DateColumn
```

etc, because SQLS has to convert e.g. the date to int or the int to date to know whether to put it in(UNION) or take it out(EXCEPT) of the result set